# Formatting the y-axis from low to high

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have to plot a Current line from a Measurement. I have the Problem that the line starts at 0,280 and than declines to nearly 0.
[My Current Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mdjz.png)
[How it´s supposed to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4hhK.png)

Can somebody help me to get the graph right?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

Current = 280#input("Ladesstrom in mA: \n")

x = []
y = []

with open('0C2.csv','r') as csvfile:
    lines = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    for row in lines:
        x.append(row[0])
        y.append(row[2])
        
liste = pd.read_csv('0C2.csv', sep=";")
Zeilen = len(liste)

letzte = pd.read_csv('0C2.csv',usecols=[2],skiprows=Zeilen-1, sep=";")      #letzte Zeile und Spalte 1 auslesen und in "letzte" Speichern
erste = pd.read_csv('0C2.csv',usecols=[2],nrows=1, sep=";")                 #Zeile 1 und Spalte 1 auslesen und in "erste" Speichern

StepsTime=(Zeilen)/5.005
StepsCurrent=(float(Current)/float(5.05))

print(int(Current))

plt.plot(x, y, color = 'g', marker = ',')

plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Current in A')
plt.title("Strommessung 0,2C")
plt.xlim(0, Zeilen)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, Zeilen, step=StepsTime))
plt.ylim(0, Current)
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, int(Current), step=StepsCurrent))
plt.savefig('books_read.png', dpi=800)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'd like to focus on the file reading in ```with open('0C2.csv','r') as csvfile```. It feels like this is not being done correctly. For instance, your x and y lists may have the headers included, as they show up in the plot image you shared. Furthermore, are you sure x and y elements are numbers? They may be strings, at the moment. I would recommend to double check this part of the code, before spending more time with the plotting part.